# Sharepoint upload document error “Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource”

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library

I m uploading file to Sharpoint online using C# code from a byte[].

Code is giving the below error:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource

I can logon to SP and crate and upload file. I have checked it is same user id which has rights or creating a list, adding documents, Full Control, and Use Remote Interfaces.

```
     public static bool UploadFile(SP sp, string folderName, string fileNameWithExtension, byte[] fileContent, TraceWriter log)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        SecureString securePwd = new SecureString();
        char[] pwdarray = sp.pwd.ToCharArray();

        foreach (var item in pwdarray)
        {
            securePwd.AppendChar(item);
        }       
        SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(sp.id, securePwd);        
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sp.url))
        {

            clientContext.Credentials = creds;
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
            fileCreationInformation.Content = fileContent;
            fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;

            fileCreationInformation.Url = fileNameWithExtension;          
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("FtpFiles");
            docs.RootFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            return result = true;            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Please guide me not getting what is wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to get the content of file in SharePoint?

We can use CSOM to achieve it.

Here is a demo for your reference and i have tested successfully.

```
    /// <summary>
/// upload file to Document Library
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <param name="documentLibraryName"></param>
/// <param name="filePath"></param>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
public static void uploadFileToDocLib(ClientContext context, string documentLibraryName, string filePath,string fileName)
{

   string siteURL = context.Url.EndsWith("/") ? context.Url.Substring(0, context.Url.Length - 1) : context.Url;

    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    FileCreationInformation newFileInfo = new FileCreationInformation()
    {
        ContentStream = fileStream,
        Url = siteURL + "/" + documentLibraryName + "/" + fileName,
        Overwrite = true
    };

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFileInfo);
    context.Load(file);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Set credential of SharePoint Online.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Set credential of SharePoint Online
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clientContext"></param>
/// <param name="userName"></param>
/// <param name="password"></param>
public static void setOnlineCredential(ClientContext clientContext,string userName,string password)
{
    //set the user name and password
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        secureString.AppendChar(c);
    }
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);           
}
```